# Swift sample code compiles but does not connect to Phantom 4

Tags: dji-sdk

I've successfully compiled the Swift sample code onto my iPhone 6S, however, the status continues to remain in Trying to connect. I'm able to connect with the DJI app itself so it must be something to do with the code or some configuration. Any tips? Also, is there any way to connect to the Phantom with the iOS simulator or is it necessary to compile onto the device to be able to connect to the remote?

- OSX: El Capitan 10.11.6
- iPhone 6S with iOS 11.0.2
- XCode 8.2

Answer (score 0):

You should read the bridge app tutorial
http://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/ios-tutorials/BridgeAppDemo.html

so that you can run your app from the iOS simulator.

As to connecting with iOS 11.0.2 - if you open your app, then un-plug and reconnect the USB cable with your app in focus, how does it go?  Some issues are being seen with multi-tasking apps into the DJI remote controllers, and it's an issue that is being worked on.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll go ahead and give that a try. I noticed the ObjectiveC codebase works but not the Swift. Documented here: https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-iOS/issues/176

Answer (score 0):

You might have to plug the lightning cable into the phone ***after*** the application has already launched, then your Phantom 4 will appear.